# проблема с Cardview

Tags: java, android, xml, cardview

Я отображаю в `CardView` список репозиториев гитхаб, которые мне возвращает поиск, но тут у меня маленькая проблемка - `CardView` не растягивается по ширине экрана.
С разметкой вроде как все хорошо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка активности

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_repo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/github"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/github_ava"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="8" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/github_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/search_repo"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_magnify" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_conteiner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CardView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repo_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="repo_name"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repo_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="repo_description" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repo_language"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="repo_language" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repo_last_update"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="repo_last_update" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем адаптере, в методе `onCreateViewHolder` как происходит инфлэйт разметки? Надо так

```
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())            .inflate(R.layout.card_listitem, parent, false);
```

Comment: Да теперь карточка растянулась на всю ширину, но и в высоту тоже выросла( на весь экран одна карточка получается

Comment: Это потому что ваша `CardView` находится в `LinearLayout`, у которого высота выставлена `match_parent`